# react-native-really-awesome-button onPress does not update function when state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I installed the `react-native-really-awesome-button` package because it has some really awesome buttons.

Unfortunately, it seems like the `onPress` handler does not work as intended.

Here is a reproducible demo: https://snack.expo.dev/@anshnanda/awesomebutton-not-working
You can clearly see that the `onPress` function just uses the initial state and is not updated with new state.

It is clear that AwesomeButton is just using the initial state value of `num` which leads me to think the function is wrapped with `useMemo` or `useCallback` (with a likely bug), however, digging through the [source code](https://github.com/rcaferati/react-native-really-awesome-button/blob/master/src/Button.tsx), I couldn't find why this happens.

I tried using `onPressIn` and `onPressOut` and those seem to be working fine, except the UX is obviously worse since the user doesn't see the slick animation that I downloaded `react-native-really-awesome-button` for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are asking for confirmation that it's a bug/issue in the `AwesomeButton`, and I agree that it is.

The `onPress` callback is stored in a React ref: ([source](https://github.com/rcaferati/react-native-really-awesome-button/blob/master/src/Button.tsx#L161-L173))

> ```
> const debouncedPress = useRef(
>   debouncedPressTime
>     ? debounce(
>         (animateProgressEnd: (callback?: any) => void) =>
>           onPress(animateProgressEnd), // <-- here
>         debouncedPressTime,
>         {
>           trailing: false,
>           leading: true,
>         }
>       )
>     : onPress // <-- here
> );
> ```

`debouncedPress` is called in a `press` handler: ([source](https://github.com/rcaferati/react-native-really-awesome-button/blob/master/src/Button.tsx#L453-L464))

> ```
> const press = () => {
>   actioned.current = true;
>   if (progressing.current === true) {
>     return;
>   }
>
>   if (progress === true) {
>     requestAnimationFrame(startProgress);
>   }
>
>   debouncedPress.current(animateProgressEnd); // <-- here
> };
> ```

`press` is called by the `handlePressOut` callback: ([source](https://github.com/rcaferati/react-native-really-awesome-button/blob/master/src/Button.tsx#L483-L508))

It's the `animateProgressEnd` handler that calls the passed `onPress` function (*debouncedPress*) though: ([source](https://github.com/rcaferati/react-native-really-awesome-button/blob/master/src/Button.tsx#L355-L392))

> ```
> const animateProgressEnd = (callback: any) => { // <-- your callback
>   if (progress !== true) {
>     return;
>   }
>
>   if (timeout?.current) {
>     clearTimeout(timeout.current);
>   }
>
>   requestAnimationFrame(() => {
>     animateTiming({
>       variable: animatedLoading,
>       toValue: 1,
>     }).start(() => {
>       Animated.parallel([
>         animateElastic({
>           variable: textOpacity,
>           toValue: 1,
>         }),
>         animateElastic({
>           variable: activityOpacity,
>           toValue: 0,
>         }),
>         animateTiming({
>           variable: loadingOpacity,
>           toValue: 0,
>           delay: 100,
>         }),
>       ]).start(() => {
>         animateRelease(() => {
>           progressing.current = false;
>           callback && callback(); // <-- called here
>           onProgressEnd && onProgressEnd();
>         });
>       });
>     });
>   });
> };
> ```

So yes, the React ref `debouncedPress` is never updated to hold a newer instance of your passed `onPress` callback handler.

To get around this you can use a React ref in your code to cache the `num` state and reference this in the `printCurrNum` handler.

Example:

```
function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = React.useState(0);
  const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = React.useState(0);

  const numRef = React.useRef(num); // <-- ref to cache num state
  React.useEffect(() => {           // <-- effect to update cache
    numRef.current = num;
  }, [num]);

  const increment = () => {
    setNum((num) => num + 1);
  };

  const printCurrNum = () => {
    console.log(numRef.current);     // <-- reference current value
    setCurrentValue(numRef.current); // <-- reference current value
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Current value according to AwesomeButton: {currentValue}</Text>
      <Text>{num}</Text>
      <AwesomeButton onPress={printCurrNum}>
        Update current value with Awesome Button
      </AwesomeButton>
      <Button title="Increment" onPress={increment} />
      <Button
        title="Update current value with native button"
        onPress={printCurrNum}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

https://snack.expo.dev/@drew.w.reese/awesomebutton-not-working

Comment: Thank you for your response Drew! That makes sense. 

How would you edit the source code for AwesomeButton to fix this issue?

Comment: @AnshNanda Ah, yeah, if you've control over that awesome-button code (*i.e. you've forked the repo and use your fork*) then I think all that's missing is a `useEffect` hook to run the same logic that's in the `useRef` hook that could re-enclose a current copy of the `onPress` callback. This is effectively the same process/pattern I've provided in my answer for the app-side.

Comment: I see -- that would work. Unnecessary question but how would you change the implementation of `AwesomeButton` to do this with cleaner, more readable code?

Comment: @AnshNanda I don't see much of an issue using the `useEffect` hook to recapture a closure over a callback. It should be sufficiently readable IMHO.

Comment: Hello all, I have pasted a fix here : https://github.com/rcaferati/react-native-really-awesome-button/issues/102#issuecomment-1321204842